# Changing Video Duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg, discord, mp4

I'm looking to change the duration of a video similar to videos that show a length of millions of minutes or increase the duration second by second in the player. I haven't managed to find any straightforward answers to this yet, the best I found was people saying to use ffmpeg, but due to my lack of knowledge of such things I haven't gotten very far. If there's more advanced solutions I'd be willing to try those as well.

Edit: There's no reason for this it's just something I wanted to try in my spare time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.